# How to validate XML with multiple XSD stored in Odoo modules

Tags: python, xml, xsd, odoo, lxml

I need to validate an xml that I generate with two XSD files provided. I am struggling because one of the XSD files references the other one and it looks that I am getting errors because of that.

The following is the "Invoice schema":

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- XSD ver.23/08/2021 -->
<xs:schema xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="../SignatureSchema.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="facturaElectronicaCompraVenta">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="cabecera">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="nitEmisor">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                        <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxInclusive value="9999999999999"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="razonSocialEmisor">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="200"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="municipio">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="25"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="telefono" nillable="true">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="25"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="numeroFactura">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                        <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxInclusive value="9999999999"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="cuf">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="cufd">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="codigoSucursal">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                        <xs:maxInclusive value="9999"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="direccion">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="500"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="codigoPuntoVenta" nillable="true">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                        <xs:maxInclusive value="9999"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="fechaEmision" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                            <xs:element name="nombreRazonSocial" nillable="true">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="500"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="codigoTipoDocumentoIdentidad">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                        <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxInclusive value="5"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="numeroDocumento">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="complemento" nillable="true">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:maxLength value="5"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="codigoCliente">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="codigoMetodoPago">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                        <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxInclusive value="308"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="numeroTarjeta" nillable="true">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                        <xs:maxInclusive value="9999999999999999"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="montoTotal">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                                        <xs:totalDigits value="17"/>
                                        <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
                                        <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="montoTotalSujetoIva">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                                        <xs:totalDigits value="17"/>
                                        <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
                                        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="codigoMoneda">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                        <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxInclusive value="154"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="tipoCambio">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                                        <xs:totalDigits value="17"/>
                                        <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
                                        <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="montoTotalMoneda">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                                        <xs:totalDigits value="17"/>
                                        <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
                                        <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="montoGiftCard" nillable="true">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                                        <xs:totalDigits value="17"/>
                                        <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
                                        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="descuentoAdicional" nillable="true">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                                        <xs:totalDigits value="17"/>
                                        <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
                                        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="codigoExcepcion" nillable="true">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                        <xs:maxInclusive value="1"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="cafc" nillable="true">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="leyenda">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="200"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="usuario">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="codigoDocumentoSector" type="xs:integer" fixed="1"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="detalle" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="500">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="actividadEconomica">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="codigoProductoSin">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                        <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxInclusive value="99999999"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="codigoProducto">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="descripcion">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="500"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="cantidad">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                                        <xs:totalDigits value="17"/>
                                        <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
                                        <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="unidadMedida">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                        <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
                                        <xs:maxInclusive value="86"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="precioUnitario">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                                        <xs:totalDigits value="17"/>
                                        <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
                                        <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="montoDescuento" nillable="true">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                                        <xs:totalDigits value="17"/>
                                        <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
                                        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="subTotal">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                                        <xs:totalDigits value="17"/>
                                        <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
                                        <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="numeroSerie" nillable="true">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="0"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="1500"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="numeroImei" nillable="true">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:minLength value="0"/>
                                        <xs:maxLength value="1500"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element ref="ds:Signature"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And the following one is the "Signature schema":

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Signature">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SignedInfo">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="CanonicalizationMethod">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="SignatureMethod">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="Reference">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="Transforms">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Transform">
                                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                            <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:string"
                                                                          use="required"/>
                                                        </xs:complexType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="DigestMethod">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="DigestValue" type="xs:string"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:attribute name="URI" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="SignatureValue" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="KeyInfo">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="X509Data">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="X509Certificate" type="xs:string"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The "Invoice schema" references the "Signature schema" with the namespace "schemaLocation" to the following location "../SignatureSchema.xsd".
I am working with Odoo and I am storing the "Invoice schema" file under "MyModule/data/xsd/sale_purchase" and the "Signature schema" uder "MyModule/data/xsd/".

So I validate my files with the following code:

```py
    def _validate_invoice_xml(self):
        root = self._get_xml_tree_root()
        # Validate generated xml
        xsd_file_path = get_module_resource('MyModule', 'data/xsd/sale_purchase', 'InvoiceSchema.xsd')
        with open(xsd_file_path) as xsd_file:
            invoice_schema = xsd_file.read()
        # Decode XSD file
        invoice_xsd = ET.fromstring(invoice_schema.encode('ascii'))
        xmlschema = ET.XMLSchema(invoice_xsd)
        validation_result = xmlschema.validate(root)
        if not validation_result:
            log = xmlschema.error_log
            error = log.last_error
            raise exceptions.ValidationError('XML file validation error:' + '\n' + str(error.message))
```

But when I run my code I get the following error:

```py
lxml.etree.XMLSchemaParseError: Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element', attribute 'ref': The QName value '{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}Signature' does not resolve to a(n) element declaration., line 344
```

I believe that the error is related with the referencing of the "Signaute schema" with schemaLocation="../SignatureSchema.xsd". But I am not sure, the files are located where they should.

Why am I getting this error and how can I avoid it?

Comment: I don't actually know python, or the APIs you are using, but it does look to me as if you are reading the file contents into a string, and then building the schema from that string; this means that the schema processor doesn't know what file the string came from, which means it won't have a base URI that it can use for resolution. Check the API specs to see if you can build the schema directly from a file name or URI, or if you can supply a base URI to the schema processor.

Comment: I took your advice on this and managed to get the absolute path to the xsd file and it looks like it's working fine. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael Kay commented, I needed to get the absolute path to the XSD file. In odoo I have managed to do it by using the following code:

```py
import os

# This gets the location of the absolute location of the python file running
current_location = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
# Replacing part of the path to point to the XSD file location
schema_file_location = current_location.replace('models', 'data/pathToMyXSDfile.xsd')
# Validate XML file
xsd_file = ET.parse(schema_file_location)
xmlschema = ET.XMLSchema(xsd_file)
validation_result = xmlschema.validate(root)
```